# html agility pack function scraping

Tags: c#, html, winforms, html-agility-pack

I have a problem as I am new in html agility pack. What I'm looking for is function from the page. The code below. I want to just take out a function named `getDirections` then replace `start` `koniec` and then repaste it into webpage again, then display it in my app. One question again, is there need to create two html files? Firt static, which never changes, just to load code, and second to display it? As I have to always replace `start` `koniec`? Thanks for help and advice!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Find directions</title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      var map = null;
      var end;
      var start;
      function getMap()
      {
        map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {credentials: ''});
        alert('');
        getDirections();
      }

      function getDirections()
      {
        start= 'start'; end= 'koniec'; 
        map.getCredentials(callRouteService);  
      }

      function callRouteService(credentials) 
      {
        var routeRequest = 'http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Routes?wp.0=' + start + '&wp.1=' + end + '&routePathOutput=Points&output=json&jsonp=routeCallback&key=' + credentials;
        var mapscript = document.createElement('script');           
        mapscript.type = 'text/javascript';           
        mapscript.src = routeRequest;
        document.getElementById('myMap').appendChild(mapscript);
      }

      function routeCallback(result)
      { 
          var output = document.getElementById("output");
          if (output)
          {
              while (output.hasChildNodes()) {
                  output.removeChild(output.lastChild); 
              }   
              var resultsHeader = document.createElement("h5");
              var resultsList = document.createElement("ol");
              output.appendChild(resultsHeader);
              output.appendChild(resultsList);
          }

          if (result && result.resourceSets && result.resourceSets.length > 0 && result.resourceSets[0].resources && result.resourceSets[0].resources.length > 0) 
          {
          //resultsHeader.innerHTML = "Bing Maps REST Route API  <br/>  Route from " + result.resourceSets[0].resources[0].routeLegs[0].startLocation.name + " to " + result.resourceSets[0].resources[0].routeLegs[0].endLocation.name;
          var resultsListItem = null;

          //for (var i = 0; i < result.resourceSets[0].resources[0].routeLegs[0].itineraryItems.length; ++i)
          //{
              //resultsListItem = document.createElement("li");
              //resultsList.appendChild(resultsListItem);
              //resultStr = result.resourceSets[0].resources[0].routeLegs[0].itineraryItems[i].instruction.text;
              //resultsListItem.innerHTML = resultStr;
          //}
          var bbox = result.resourceSets[0].resources[0].bbox; 
          var viewBoundaries = Microsoft.Maps.LocationRect.fromLocations(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(bbox[0], bbox[1]), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(bbox[2], bbox[3]));
          map.setView({ bounds: viewBoundaries}); 
          var routeline = result.resourceSets[0].resources[0].routePath.line; var routepoints = new Array(); 
          for (var i = 0; i < routeline.coordinates.length; i++) 
          { 
              routepoints[i]=new Microsoft.Maps.Location(routeline.coordinates[i][0], routeline.coordinates[i][1]);
          } 
          var routeshape = new Microsoft.Maps.Polyline(routepoints, {strokeColor:new Microsoft.Maps.Color(200,0,0,200)}); 

          var startPushpinOptions = {anchor: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(10, 32) }; 
          var startPin= new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(routeline.coordinates[0][0], routeline.coordinates[0][1]), startPushpinOptions); 

          var endPushpinOptions = {anchor: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(10, 32)}; 
          var endPin= new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(routeline.coordinates[routeline.coordinates.length-1][0], routeline.coordinates[routeline.coordinates.length-1][1]), endPushpinOptions); 
          map.entities.push(startPin); 
          map.entities.push(endPin); 
          map.entities.push(routeshape); 
      }

      else
      {
          if (typeof(result.errorDetails) != 'undefined')
          {
              resultsHeader.innerHTML = result.errorDetails[0];
          }
              alert("No Route found");
          }
      }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body onload="getMap();">
      <div id='myMap' style="position:relative; width:400px; height:400px;"></div>

      <div id="output"></div>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your problem is.  Are you getting an error with the above code?  If so what is it?  How is what you have, not working?

Comment: When im ascraping, its all good, but when I try to load new node to html it's getting wrong format, page doesnt load. Look at my code:

 textBox4.Text = changeSubString;
                foreach (HtmlNode node in htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//head/script"))
                {
                    changeString = node.InnerText;
                    changeSubString = changeString;
                }